# 複数のハッシュリテラルから目的のハッシュを検索

Tags: ruby

もしかしたら過去の質問等で出ているのかもしれませんが、見つけきれないので質問させて頂きます。
hashという結果が以下のように複数のハッシュで返ってきた場合に、目的のハッシュリテラルのみを表示したいのですがなかなか上手くいきません。

```
array = {"symbol"=>"X", "value"=>"Y", "examle"=>"Z"},
        {"symbol"=>"A", "value"=>"S", "examle"=>"D"},
        {"symbol"=>"L", "value"=>"K", "examle"=>"J"},
                             .
                             .
                             .
        {"symbol"=>"M", "value"=>"N", "examle"=>"B"},
```

このような場合、["symbol" => "L"] のハッシュリテラルの{"symbol"=>"L", "value"=>"K", "examle"=>"J"} を検索したい場合はどのようにすればいいのでしょうか。

```
array.each do |hash|
  p hash["symbol"]
end
```

などでsymbolのみを全て表示してそこから検索などはなんとか出来たのですが、もっと上手く検索できないものかな思い質問させてい頂いています。
お願いします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。上手くいきました。selectを使えばよかったんですね！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array.select { |h| h['symbol'] == 'L' }
```

ruby では、コレクションっぽいものは、 [Enumerable](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/class/Enumerable.html) を include しています。

select は、ブロックの戻り値が真になるものだけを選択するメソッドです。